# AWS Redshift: Error in fetching Last ID column value after an insert statement

Tags: redshift

I have asked this question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76489253/error-in-fetching-last-id-column-value-after-an-insert-statement-in-aws-redshift). But reposting here due to appropriateness.

I want to fetch the last ID number after an INSERT event in AWS Redshift. For this, I have written a Stored Procedure in AWS Redshift as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myschema.uspgtest(paramname varchar(10),runID int, INOUT 
activitylogid integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
 DECLARE
   v_WorkflowID BIGINT;Status VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';cnt INT;  
 BEGIN
  ----Internal SQL Codes----
  ----The below code is part of main code-----
   IF (WorkflowID IS NULL OR Status = 'Completed' OR cnt = 0) THEN
   INSERT INTO myschema."Table_1" ("Status", "CreatedDatetime", 
   "UpdatedDatetime", "Type")
   VALUES ('In-Progress', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, paramname) 
   RETURNING ID INTO v_WorkflowID; 
   END IF;

   INSERT INTO myschema."Table_2" ("ParentActivityLogID", "CreatedDateTime", 
   "UpdatedDateTime", "WorkflowID","RunID")
   VALUES (0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, v_WorkflowID,runID) RETURNING 
   ActivityLogID INTO activitylogid;   
END;
$$
```

The above SP is throwing an error as below:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING" Where: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function 
"uspgtest" near line 18 [ErrorId: <errorID>
```

What I am missing here?